# three.js dae model is black or dark

Tags: 3d, webgl, three.js

heres my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/zsitro/gYhrY/ (just to show... doesnt works at fiddle)

It can load:
- THREE.js inbuilt plane and cube and a light..
- the models (1 cube and a walking creature).

Its all ok, but the problem is the creature is almost black (soo dark), and the cube is total black. If I remove the light, it shows its texture and the monster is brighter a bit.
[image]

I cannot find resources how to avoid this black thing and make my spotlight work.

The spotlight is set up properly I think, because  the lower cube and the axis lines are shown well (and cast shadow as expected).

If I switch the light direction -> nothing changes except the red cube casts shadow as expected again...

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of material is being applied? Figure that out and then look at the internals and modify some of the properties effected by lighting.

Some good places to start are

```
    this.color = parameters.color 
this.ambient = parameters.ambient
this.specular = parameters.specular
this.shininess = parameters.shininess
```

where this is a material of X type. Adjusting the ambient will bring the base brightness up.

Ok I see it's MeshBasicMaterial. I would try changing it to a phong or lambert material and setting the ambient value to greater than the default.

Answer (score 0):

looking at your fiddle, i think the main problem is the angle you are viewing from, and the fact that you have a spotlight, but no ambient light. try adding ambient light as follows and see if this helps some:

first, you are not setting a light color on your spotlight, so it's just harsh white, so you'll want to do something as follows, and this will help you:

```
scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x020202 ) );
```

if that is still too dark, try something like:

```
scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x040404 ) );
```

once you find the right balance, you'll be set :) just remember that your ambient light is set in hex with 0xrrggbb so if you want to cut everything in the color in half, you use 020202, but if you wanted more blue, you'd use 020204, for example, just remember it's ambient light you're working with and very easy to over-saturate light in the scene, so keep it low, i usually stick around .2 * my point or directional light source (e.g. sunlight, lamp, whatever)
let me know if this helps :)